# systemd-resolve not apply settings based on network interface

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved, systemd-networkd

I want to config systemd-resolve for working with different dns servers based on network interface. But when I create config un the /etc/systemd/network/tun.network nothing is happen.

1. My tun.network file

```
[Match]
Name=tun

[Network]
DNS=10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2
Domains=~.mycorp
```

2. Rebooting the systemd-resolve. `service systemd-resolved restart`
3. Print `resolvectl status`

```
Link 3 (wlp9s0)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 192.168.3.1
    DNS Domain: ~.

...

Link 16 (tun)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

But I am waiting to see something like this:

```
Link 3 (tun)
   ...
   DNS Servers: 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2
   DNS Domain: ~.mycorp
```

My question is how to properly config systemd-resolve for working with different dns servers based on network interface

Comment: Perhaps you should restart systemd-networkd *as well*?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. Thanks @iBug for his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378168/systemd-resolve-not-apply-settings-based-on-network-interface#comment2374583_1378168)

After `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` dns servers appears in the output of  `resolvectl status`